# Custom HtmlHelper extension method usage problem in asp.net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have converted my classic asp.net mvc views to razor. In a view there is a usage of an extension method (it has overloads) of HtmlHelper:

```
@Html.CustomAction<AccountController, LogOnModel>("displayText", x => x.Register())
```

And CustomAction signature is:

```
public static HtmlString CustomAction<TController, TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> view, string displayText, Expression<Func<TController, object>> where TController : Controller
```

I have also enabled view compilation at build time (through .proj file). When I build the project I get these errors pointing to that line:

- Argument 1: cannot convert from
  'method group' to
  'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'
- The best overloaded method match for 
  'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
  has some invalid arguments

What is the reason of these errors? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Razor parser sees `<` and thinks it's an HTML tag.  Therefore, it only parses `Html.CustomAction` as the expression.

You need to wrap the call in parentheses to force it to treat the entire call as a single expression:

```
@(Html.CustomAction<AccountController, LogOnModel>("displayText", x => x.Register()))
```